# How to cycle in Finder autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder, autocomplete

For example I want to go to `~/Library/Application Support`.

By pressing command+shift+g in Finder and type `~/Library/App`, Finder will autocomplete it with `~/Library/Application Scripts`.

I need to delete `cripts` and type `u` to get `~/Library/Application Support`.

Is there some magic to get the result with less steps?

Comment: Can you press `Tab`? I'm not on a Mac right now, but that should work.

Comment: @slhck It doesn't work. Just confirms the current suggestion.

Comment: Pressing twice doesn't work either?

Comment: @slhck Not work. The cursor flew to the end on first tab pressing. An error sound on second pressing.